# Define the sequence $aₙ=20+n²$ and $dₙ=\gcd(aₙ , aₙ₊₁)$ Find with proof the values dₙ takes.

Tags: number-theory

I have tried to sopve this question and found the answer, but i cant find a proof. My answer is $1,3,9,27$. Thanks in advance to those who help me.

Comment: How did you get $9$, exactly?

Comment: Well gcd of 36(20+16) and 45(20+25)

Comment: Right. I thought those were _in order_, not just the list of possible values. As in $d_0=1,d_1=3,d_2=9$, which would be wrong, as $d_2=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$\text{G.C.D} (a_n,a_{n+1}) = \text{G.C.D }(n^2 +20 , n^2+20+2n+1)$$
$$  = \text{G.C.D } (n^2+20,2n+1)$$

$$n^2 +20 = \left(2n+1 \right)\left(\frac n2-\frac14 \right) + \frac{81}4$$

Since we get $81$ in the remainder , all the possible values of $d_n$ would be a factor of $81$.

$$\text{Hence ,  } d_n \in \left( 1,3,9,27 ,81\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm done now.

Comment: @Okabe Remember , $81 $ is also a possible value.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out after ur hint

Comment: I am not able to figure it out... Can anybody please elaborate this for me.... Thanks

Comment: @Vasu090 Divide the $a_{n+1}$ with $a_n$ and find the remainder.Since the number must be divisible , $a_n$ must also divide the remainder.

Comment: Can you please explain how do you get the conclusion from here: $$n^2 +20 = \left(2n+1 \right)\left(\frac n2-\frac14 \right) + \frac{81}4$$